# Shuffle data in LMDB file

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I already have an existing [LMDB](http://symas.com/mdb/)(Symas Lightning Memory-Mapped Database) file which is created for [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/). Is there any possible way to shuffle the data in already existing LMDB to create a new LMDB with data shuffled. Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful.

Comment: why would you like to "reshuffle" the dataset?

Comment: I think shuffling would help in training caffe network. LMDB was created by sequentially reading the data because of which data in the LMDB is grouped by class. If a batch is picked then most of the time batch contains data of same class/group. Which is not help me to train caffe network.

Comment: can you re-create the lmdb? `create_imagest` has a flag for shuffling

Comment: Dataset is converted to lmdb by modified version of create_imageset for 3D data which shuffle logic cannot be implemented.

Comment: that's a pickle...

Comment: if you Google around you'll find how to use Python to read/write lmdb for caffe. I suppose you can modify the lmdb using python

Comment: alternatively, you can shuffle the text file listing all your input data and use the shuffled list as an input to your modified create_imagest

Comment: The 3D data is read into datum using opencv Mat and there are no txt file listing created as in caffe.

Answer (score 1):

LMDB traverses data according to the lexicological order of the key. You can prepend a random number to your current key and the data will be shuffled accordingly. I am also investigating an efficient way to rewrite the keys randomly between epochs as I would like to use Batch normalization in my data set.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer given by @Manolo, while creating the LMDB dataset as suggested [here](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/), I concatenated a random int to the beginning as follows:

```
random.seed(i)
str_id = '{:05}'.format(random.randint(1,70000))+'{:05}'.format(i)
```

I chose 70000, since my LMDB had about 72000 images.

Comment: `random.seed()` doen't give true randomness. Very inefficient and takes long time to shuffle large database file.