# Copying LMDB to another LMDB reduces file size

Tags: python, caffe, lmdb

To shuffle the data in already existing lmdb ([Trying to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108120/shuffle-data-in-lmdb-file)). I retrieved the data, shuffled and wrote back to new lmdb. But the when I checked the lmdb file size, it is reduced. Old lmdb file size : 3792896 but the New lmdb file size : 2314240.

Python code Inplemented :

```
import lmdb
from random import shuffle

lst_data = [];

env = lmdb.open('val_3', readonly=True);
with env.begin() as txn:
    cursor = txn.cursor();
    for key, value in cursor:
        innerlst_data = [key,value];
        lst_data.append(innerlst_data);

shuffle(lst_data);

env1 = lmdb.open('mod_val_3');
with env1.begin(write=True) as txn1:
    for i in range(len(lst_data)):
        str_id = '{:08}'.format(i);
        txn1.put(str_id.encode('ascii'),lst_data[i][1]);
```

Reference for the code is taken from [here](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/).
Any suggestions/ideas would be helpful.

Comment: This is fairly common. The old database may have wasted space due to deleted items. That's why databases have functions like SQLite's VACUUM. With some databases it's also possible that there are indexes in the old database that don't exist in the new one, which take up disk space, but it doesn't look as though lmdb lets you specify what gets indexed.

Comment: I tried to repeat the above process in a loop and lmdb file size gets to '0'. So I think it's not the waste space getting deleted but the data is getting deleted, which I don't understand.

Comment: Huh. Yeah that is weird.

Comment: Have you tried to call cursor.first() before iterating over it?

Comment: No, I had not used cursor.first(). I think using it will cause the cursor position to be changed to the first record.

Comment: That's the point ;-). It seems that you have to position explicitly the cursor before iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mdb_stat` to see the number of entries in the database. This should confirm if your copy worked correctly.

Comment: can you please provide a more detailed example on how to use `mdb_stat`?

Comment: mdb_stat -fear <dbpath> will give you information on free list usage, environment info, all sub databases and current readers

Comment: mdb_stat needs to be compiled. The C implementation is available on [github](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/tree/mdb.master/libraries/liblmdb)

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of the lmdb Python wrappers (at least as of 1.3.0) include [an environment `copy` method](https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/#lmdb.Environment.copy), which has a `compact` option that appears to do what @Ravi was trying to do. Use it like this (adjusting `lmdb.open` parameters as necessary):

```py
# Copy old database into new one with compacting
# Old database is ~34G from deleting 200k of 400k original records
with lmdb.open(
    "200k-split.lmdb",
    map_size=109951162777,
    subdir=False,
    meminit=False,
    map_async=True,
) as env:
    env.copy(path="200k-split-compacted.lmdb", compact=True)
```

You can then verify that the compacted file has the same number of records as the original file...

```py
with lmdb.open(
    "200k-split.lmdb",
    map_size=109951162777,
    subdir=False,
    meminit=False,
    map_async=True,
) as env:
    print(env.stat())

# {'psize': 4096, 'depth': 3, 'branch_pages': 19, 
#  'leaf_pages': 2228, 'overflow_pages': 3600000, 'entries': 200000}
```

```py
with lmdb.open(
    "200k-split-compacted.lmdb",
    map_size=109951162777,
    subdir=False,
    meminit=False,
    map_async=True,
) as env:
    print(env.stat())

# {'psize': 4096, 'depth': 3, 'branch_pages': 19,
#  'leaf_pages': 2228, 'overflow_pages': 3600000, 'entries': 200000}
```

...but a vastly smaller file size.

```sh
> ls -lah *.lmdb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 samueldy samueldy 14G Mar  2 03:31 200k-split-compacted.lmdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 samueldy samueldy 34G Mar  2 03:29 200k-split.lmdb
```