# LMDB Environment.copy() raises lmdb.Error: mdb_env_copy3: No such file or directory

Tags: lmdb, palmdb

When I try to compress a lmdb database by copying it to a different location as compressed version (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321334/23008479) the error *lmdb.Error: mdb_env_copy3: No such file or directory* is raised. Could you please help me further?

Thank you for your efforts in advance.

minimal working example

```py
import lmdb
import os

PATH_0 = 'test.mdb'
PATH_1 = 'test_compact.mdb'

path_0 = os.path.abspath(PATH_0)
path_1 = os.path.abspath(PATH_1)  # path to copy db_1, the compressed version of db_0

db_0 = lmdb.open(path_0)  # db to copy
db_0.copy(path=path_1, compact=True)  # raises path not found error
```